# Reading aws config and credentials from resources folder using aws java sdk version 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I have moved my aws credentials from ~/.aws/credentials to resources folder of maven project . the folder structure looks like this
resources/aws/
->config
->credentials
I am using aws java sdk version 2+ . How can i read the values from resources folder to get region, access keys , create bucket and perform operations.

Answer (score 2):

You should not place credentials files in resources directory. AWS Java SDK [supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/credentials.html) credential files in `~/.aws` out-of-the box:

> The following list shows the supported credential retrieval techniques:
>
> 1. **Java system properties**–`aws.accessKeyId` and `aws.secretAccessKey`. The AWS SDK for Java uses the [`SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/index.html?software/amazon/awssdk/auth/credentials/SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider.html) to load these credentials.
> 2. **Environment variables**–**AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID** and **AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY**. The AWS SDK for Java uses the [`EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/index.html?software/amazon/awssdk/auth/credentials/EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.html) class to load these credentials.
> 3. **The default credential profiles file**– The specific location of this file can vary per platform, but is typically located at `~/.aws/credentials`. This file is shared by many of the AWS SDKs and by the AWS CLI. The AWS SDK for Java uses the [`ProfileCredentialsProvider`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/index.html?software/amazon/awssdk/auth/credentials/ProfileCredentialsProvider.html) to load these credentials.
>
>    You can create a credentials file by using the aws configure command provided by the AWS CLI. You can also create it by editing the file with a text editor. For information about the credentials file format, see AWS Credentials File Format.
> 4. **Amazon ECS container credentials**– This is loaded from Amazon ECS if the environment variable `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` is set. The AWS SDK for Java uses the [`ContainerCredentialsProvider`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/index.html?software/amazon/awssdk/auth/credentials/ContainerCredentialsProvider.html) to load these credentials.
> 5. **Instance profile credentials**– This is used on Amazon EC2 instances, and delivered through the Amazon EC2 metadata service. The AWS SDK for Java uses the [`InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/index.html?software/amazon/awssdk/auth/credentials/InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.html) to load these credentials.

So, either use `ProfileCredentialsProvider` or pass the credentials via system properties or environment variables and use `SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider` / `EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Java SDK v2 does not support getting credentials from the resource folder (classpath) directly.

As an alternative, you can put AWS credentials in a properties file in the resource folder:

[[project]/src/test/resources/aws-credentials.properties:

```
aws_access_key_id = xxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxx
```

Spring config:

```
    <util:properties id="awsCredentialFile"
      location="classpath:aws-credentials.properties"/>
```

and your code:

```
  @Resource(name = "awsCredentialFile")
  public void setProperties(Properties properties) {
    this.accessKey = properties.getProperty("aws_access_key_id");
    this.secretKey = properties.getProperty("aws_secret_access_key");
  }

  StaticCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey, secretKey));
    S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
        .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
        .build();
```